# Ошибка в сортировке массива чисел

Tags: c++

код должен отсеивать все элементы массива не входящие в границы [a b], массив сжимается, все не вошедшие элементы к нулю и вправо, выдает неправильный ответ, не могу найти в чем ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   float mas [10] = {4, 3, 9.4, -0.7, 1, 5, 9, 1.3, 9, 0.66};
   float a = 3;
   float b = 6;
   for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
       if(mas[i]<a || mas[i]>b){
          for(int j = i++; j < 10; j++){
           mas[j-1] = mas[j];
          }
          mas[9] = 0;
          i--;
        }
}

  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
       std::cout<<mas[i]<<std::endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге получаю ответ `4 9.4 1 9 9 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: "выдает неправильный ответ" - какой?

Comment: 4
9.4
1
9
9
0
0
0
0
0

Comment: А не надо изменять массив, по которому идете. От этого возникают вот такие трудноуловимые баги. Нужно создавать и наполнять новый массив.

Comment: https://www.ideone.com/tx9j0T

Comment: Вы используете `i++` вместо `i + 1` в `int j = i++`. Также, так как 0 не удовлетворяет условию, то как только Вы попадёте на конечные нули (которые Вы сами добавили, если в массиве есть хоть один элемент не удовлетворяющий условию), Ваша программа попадёт в вечный цикл, так как Вы мешаете продвижению цикла посредством `i--`.

Comment: А какой ответ правильным считается? Нужно ли сохранять порядок "хороших элементов"? В общем, задача пока не поставлена по уму, нужна точная формулировка.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define str_format \
std::fixed << std::setw(4) << std::setprecision(2) << std::setfill('0')

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void print_arr(T(&arr)[N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << str_format << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    float arr[] = { 4, 3, 9.4, 7, 1, 5, 9, 1.3, 9, 0.66 };
    float l_bound = 3,
          h_bound = 6;

    int arr_len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    float temp_val;
    for (int i = 0, r = 0; (i + r) < arr_len;) {
        if (arr[i] < l_bound || arr[i] > h_bound) {
            arr[i] = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < arr_len - 1; ++j) {
                temp_val = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp_val;
            }
            ++r;
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
        print_arr(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Промежуток [a,b] с квадратными скобками включает числа 3 и 6, поэтому используем ">=" "<=". Мне пришло в голову только создать второй массив и записывать в него элементы первого. Если хотите, можете дальше просто переписывать все элементы второго в первый. Хотя мне кажется это лишнее. И потом, я не понял что значит "массив сжимается". Куда тогда записывать остальные элементы не входящие от a до b. Если вы сдвигаете элементы вправо, то куда пихать 0? Массив должен расширяться? У нас всего 10 элементов, тогда 0 будем 11-ым. В общем следующая программа выводит сначала элементы входящие в промежуток от a до b, затем справа налево записывает остальные элементы.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /*устанавливаем размер массива*/
    int razmermassiva = 10;
   float mas [razmermassiva] = {4, 3, 9.4, -0.7, 1, 5, 9, 1.3, 9, 0.66};
   float mas2 [razmermassiva];
   float a = 3;
   float b = 6;


   int i, j, k;
   i=j=k=0;
   for(i = 0; i<razmermassiva; i++){
        /*отсеиваем элементы массива*/
       if(mas[i]>=a && mas[i]<=b){
            /*записываем элемент массива в другой массив*/
            mas2[j]=mas[i];
            j++;
        }
        else{
        /*записываем остальные элементы справа налево*/
        mas2[razmermassiva-(k+1)]=mas[i];
        k++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<razmermassiva; i++){
        std::cout <<mas2[i]<<" ";
    }
        std::cout <<std::endl;
  }
```

Если хотите изменять динамически размер массивов, то лучше использовать векторы...
Прежде чем, как получить ответ, сначала задайте правильно вопрос, и будет вам решение.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, я неправильно понял. Первая программа тоже неплохая, поэтому оставлю ее и напишу новый ответ. Здесь также я присваиваю остальным элементам ноль. 
Но про "сжимание массива" я так и не понял

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /*устанавливаем размер массива*/
    int razmermassiva = 10;
   float mas [razmermassiva] = {4, 3, 9.4, -0.7, 1, 5, 9, 1.3, 9, 0.66};
   float mas2 [razmermassiva];
   float a = 3;
   float b = 6;


   int i, j, k;
   i=j=k=0;
   for(i = 0; i<razmermassiva; i++){
        /*отсеиваем элементы массива*/
       if(mas[i]>=a && mas[i]<=b){
            /*записываем элемент массива в другой массив*/
            mas2[j]=mas[i];
            j++;
        }
        else{
        /*записываем 0 справа налево */
        mas2[razmermassiva-(k+1)]=0;
        k++;
        }
    }

    /*переписываем массив обратно и выводим*/
    for(i = 0; i<razmermassiva; i++){
        mas[i]=mas2[i];
        std::cout <<mas[i]<<" ";
    }
        std::cout <<std::endl;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так ещё. Работает за O(n), в отличии от вашего O(n^2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const size_t mas_size = 10;
    float mas[mas_size] = { 4, 3, 9.4, -0.7, 1, 5, 9, 1.3, 9, 0.66 };
    float a = 3;
    float b = 6;
    auto it = remove_if(mas, mas + mas_size, [a, b](float x) {
        return x >= a && x <= b;
    });

    for_each(it, mas + mas_size, [](float &x) { x = 0; });

    for (int i = 0; i < mas_size; i++) {
        std::cout << mas[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Или так, тоже за O(n)

```
...остальное...
size_t pos;
for (pos = 0; pos < mas_size; ++pos) {
    if (mas[pos] >= a && mas[pos] <= b)
        break;
}

for (size_t i = pos+1; i < mas_size; ++i) {
    if (!(mas[i] >= a && mas[i] <= b)) {
        mas[pos++] = mas[i];
        mas[i] = 0;
    }
}
...остальное...
```

Comment: `for_each(it, mas + mas_size, [](float &x) { x = 0; });` можно переписать как `std::fill(it, mas + mas_size, 0);`.